# Why does my code for No.669 in leetcode run well in VS2019, but report error in leetcode?

Tags: c++

This is my code.

```
class Solution {
public:
    TreeNode* emptyBST(TreeNode* root)
    {
        if(!root)   return NULL;
        root->left = emptyBST(root->left);
        root->right = emptyBST(root->right);
        delete root;
        return NULL;
    }
    
    TreeNode* trimBST(TreeNode* root, int low, int high) {
        if(!root)   return NULL;

        if(root->val < low)
        {
            root->left = emptyBST(root->left);
            TreeNode* temp = root->right;
            delete(root);
            return trimBST(temp, low, high);
        }
        else if (root->val > high)
        {
            root->right = emptyBST(root->right);
            TreeNode* temp = root->left;
            delete(root);
            return trimBST(temp, low, high);
        }

        root->left = trimBST(root->left,low,high);
        root->right = trimBST(root->right,low,high);
        return root;
    }
};
```

It report error in 4th example of leetcode. Just like below.

```
=================================================================
==29==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x603000000348 at pc 0x0000003729e5 bp 0x7ffe97aba9f0 sp 0x7ffe97aba9e8
READ of size 8 at 0x603000000348 thread T0
    #3 0x7f0f2b4d60b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
0x603000000348 is located 8 bytes inside of 24-byte region [0x603000000340,0x603000000358)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #3 0x7f0f2b4d60b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #4 0x7f0f2b4d60b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c067fff8010: fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa 00 00 00 07 fa fa
  0x0c067fff8020: fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa
  0x0c067fff8030: fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd
  0x0c067fff8040: fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8050: fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fd fd fd fa
=>0x0c067fff8060: fa fa fd fd fd fa fa fa fd[fd]fd fa fa fa 00 00
  0x0c067fff8070: 00 fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8080: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8090: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff80a0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff80b0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==29==ABORTING
```

I try this code in VS20119, and it runs well.
If I abandonthe two lines of "delete(root);", it run well in leetcode too.
But after I add these two lines, it reports error again. I do not want to abandon these two lines, because I want to clean the memory I am supposed to clean.

Comment: what is `TreeNode` ? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: A few (unrelated) things: First of all the name `emptyBST` is kind of ambiguous, does it check if a tree *is* "empty", or does it make the tree "empty"? There's also no need for it to return anything, if it will always return the exact same value. You might as well pass the argument by reference and assign `nullptr` to it. And with that the next point, `NULL` is more or less a C backward compatible macro, which have been discouraged since long ago. Use `nullptr` for null pointers instead.

Comment: This is the definition for a binary tree node.
 struct TreeNode {
     int val;
     TreeNode *left;
     TreeNode *right;
     TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
     TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}
 };

Comment: As for the crash, I recommend you create your own [mre] and build locally using *sanitizers* to find possible problems. You could also use tools such as Valgrind to help you find problems.

Comment: Fwiw, using both your code and you're commented treenode (which belongs in the posted question; not a comment) and both valgrind and full address sanitizer running handily, I cannot reproduce your error. Lord knows I tried.

Comment: This error does not occur locally, it just occur in leecode.